# Data analytics using python or hadoop?

Tags: anaconda, data-science, data-analysis

Which technology is efficient to analyze the data hadoop or python? and which technology is speed between the above two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Hadoop mostly uses spark. If the underlying framework you are using to analyse or crunch your data contains spark, you are good to go with either Scala, PySpark or maybe R. Using alone python won't give you benefits of Spark which makes data analysis faster and also various transformations on Big Data. So whichever you use, its about using spark.

Scala or PySpark : both contains almost all of these features.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever analyzing data and considering speed as a criteria, two key components determine the speed: The amount of data you have and where the data is located.

If you have [Big Data](https://www.sas.com/en_us/insights/big-data/what-is-big-data.html), consider using Hadoop or Spark to analyze it. This will make it much faster and you will not be dependent of load time. If you have a few gigabytes of data it maybe best to use python but it still may slow down your machine.

Now to address where the data is, if you have your data on premise then python is the best approach. If your data is located in cloud server, then [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/big-data/), [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/big-data/), or even [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/) have big data tools available to make this data exploration easier. All three cloud systems have big data tools available for use.

So in terms of speed, it really depends on the two constraints. If you have Big Data and your data is located in a cloud system. Consider using Hadoop to analyze your data. If you have only a few gigabytes of data and on-premise, use python to analyze your data.